# Error dotnet run

Tags: c#, linux, .net, debian

Tengo instalado el sdk para programar en .net desde debian10 en android con un gestor de linux
y al ejectutar dotnet run me sale esto =>

> dotnet run
>
> /home/yandrak/.net/app/app.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK
>   'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.
>
> The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.

Comment: Ejecuta este comando `dotnet --list-sdks` y lo más probable es que tengas que instalar el sdk que estás especificando

Answer (score 1):

- Si eliminamos la opción de que no está instalado el SDK en la maquina, lo más probable es que no tengas configuradas las variables de entorno, por lo cual cuando quieras correr el ***dotnet.exe***, este comando no estará disponible.

Intentá agregando en la variable de entorno **PATH** la carpeta donde se encuentra el ejecutable dotnet:

1. Abrir *"Editar Variables de entorno del sistema"*
2. En la pestaña *"Opciones Avanzadas"* **=>** *"Variables de entorno"*
3. Luego en la tabla *"Variables de sistema"* buscar la variable llamada **PATH**.
4. **PATH** **=>** *"Editar"*.
5. Crear una NUEVA entrada con el el directorio:  `C:\Program Files\dotnet\`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego puedes verificar que el comando esté accesible ejecutando:

```
dotnet --version
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad!.

**Saludos atte! :)**

Comment: Gracias por contestar, pero estoy utilizando debian no windows por lo que tu respuesta no me soluciona el problema, Un saludo